# Elastic IP is still billing after deleting associated instance and discosiating IP-es

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing

I have reviewed many similar topics and tried the following methods:

1. deleted active ec2 instance
2. disassociated and remove elastic IP
3. even deleted snapshat and ami

however billing is still increasing every day, what else should i do to stop this process?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to get the obvious question out of the way, you're sure you're checking in the correct region? Have you checked other regions for elastic IP addresses?

Comment: A good point to check, I will check other regions as well.

Comment: The final screenshot clearly shows it is an Elastic IP in `us-west-2 (Oregon)`. Is that the region being viewed in the other screenshots?